# Query two SQL entries?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a SQL database I'm trying to query with PHP. It's for user accounts and I need to test if a certain username and password combination exist in the database.

Currently, I can check if just a username exists by using:

```
 <?php
session_start();

include "config.php";

if($_POST['nameQuery']) {

$query = "SELECT * FROM ichatlogin WHERE name = '" .$_POST['nameQuery']. "'";  
$result = mysql_query($query);  
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) { 
        //User exists
        echo '1'; 
    } else { 
        mysql_query($query);
    //User does not exist
    echo '0'; 
    }
}
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's a serious security hole to use POSTed arguments directly in your SQL statement. A malicious user could send arbitrary SQL commands into this system.

Comment: Why send the query a second time (in the 'else' clause)?

Comment: XKCD about the dangers of SQL Injection: http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Or on a more serious note, here's a php doc explaining the danger and how to avoid it: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make as many logical comparisons as you need. Combine them with AND or OR as appropriate.

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nameQuery']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

$query = "SELECT * FROM ichatlogin WHERE name = '$name' AND password = '$password' LIMIT 1";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
session_start();

include "config.php";

if($_POST['nameQuery'] && $_POST['passwordQuery']) {

$query = "SELECT * FROM ichatlogin WHERE name = '" .$_POST['nameQuery'] . ' AND WHERE password = ' . $_POST['passwordQuery'];  
$result = mysql_query($query);  
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) { 
        //User exists
        echo '1'; 
    } else { 
        mysql_query($query);
    //User does not exist
    echo '0'; 
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Using this, I'm getting the error "Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/cacton/public_html/cardinalchat/appquery2/query2.php on line 10
0"

Comment: Nevermind, I got it working. I had to decrypt the MD5 from the password first. Thanks guys!

Comment: You cannot decrypt an MD5 hash. It's not encryption, it's hashing, which is one-way. To see if the passwords are equal, you compare the hashes. `WHERE name = '$name' AND password = MD5('$password')`

Comment: @Chase glad its working nw , if you find my ans useful then please check it . thanks.